# Unable to set-up Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, installation, pyspark

I have installed Pyspark and Findspark using conda environment and added their paths to environment variables.

I execute following code:

```
import findspark
import pyspark
findspark.find()
```

I get the output as:

```
'C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts'
```

Then I execute:

```
findspark.init("C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts")
```

The output I get is:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please use a Docker container https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook and save yourself the trouble.